# How to integrate Ninjaforms with TFS?

Tags: tfs, integration, ninja-forms

What is the best way to integrate Ninja Forms with Microsoft Team Foundation Server?

We want to create a backlog item when we submit the Ninja Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach so far was using Webhooks plugin in Ninja Form and POST the form data to TFS using TFS API.

References:

[Webhooks plugin for Ninja Forms](https://ninjaforms.com/extensions/webhooks/)

[How to create work item using TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items)

[Authenticating with personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats)